# What does '0' mean in a subtraction?

Tags: c++

```
class Complex
{
public:
    int a,b;
    void input(string s)
    {
        int v1=0;
        int i=0;
        while(s[i]!='+')
        {
            v1=v1*10+s[i]-'0'; // <<---------------------------here
            i++;
        }
        while(s[i]==' ' || s[i]=='+'||s[i]=='i')
        {
            i++;
        }
        int v2=0;
        while(i<s.length())
        {
            v2=v2*10+s[i]-'0';
            i++;
        }
        a=v1;
        b=v2;
    }
};
```

This is a class complex and the function input inputs  string and convert it into integers a and b of class complex.
**what is the requirement of subtracting '0' in this  code**

Comment: `std::cout << (int)'0';`

Comment: @CássioRenan it does not answer why somebody would subtract it.

Answer (score 8):

The characters representing the digits, '0' thru '9' have values that are (and must be) sequential. For example, in the [ASCII character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) the '0' character is encoded with the value 48 (decimal), '1' is 49, '2' is 50 and so on, until '9', which is 57. Other encoding systems may use different *actual values* for the digits (for example, in [EBCDIC](http://ascii-table.com/ebcdic-table.php), '0' is 240 and '9' is 249), but the C standard ***requires*** that they are sequentially congruent. From §5.2.1 of the [C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:201x) Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>   each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>   one greater than the value of the previous.

Thus, when you subtract the `'0'` character from another character that represents a digit, you get the *numerical value* of that digit (rather than its encoded value).

So, in the code:

```c
int a = '6' - '0';
```

the value of the `a` will be 6 (and similarly for other digits).

The reason for not just using a value of (say) `48`, rather than writing `'0'` is that the former would *only* work on systems that use that particular (i.e. ASCII) character encoding, whereas the latter will work on *any* compliant system.

Answer (score 1):

"What does '0' means in c++" - The symbol `'0'` designates a single `char`acter (constant) with the value `0`, which, when interpreted as an ASCII character (which it will be) has the numerical value 0x30 (or 48 in decimal). So, you are basically just subtracting 48.

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite understand the logic of this function but I hope this will help:
'0' is a character  literal for 0 in ASCII. The [] operator of string returns a character. So most likely s[i] - '0' is supposed to get you the digit stored in s[i] as a character. Example: '3' -'0' = 3. Note lack of ' around the 3.

Answer (score 0):

> The C and C++ standards require that the characters '0'..'9' be
>   contiguous and increasing. So to convert one of those characters to
>   the digit that it represents you subtract '0' and to convert a digit
>   to the character that represents it you add '0'.

**In this case the goal is to convert the character in the integer digit that represent.**